# linear Algebra Kernel and Image Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

let there be S,T linear operators working in vector space $U$;  $$ T,S : U \rightarrow U $$

Prove that:$$ Ker(ST)=U \Longleftrightarrow ImT \subseteq Ker(S)  $$

Attempt at a Solution:

Left to right Direction:

$ Ker(ST)=U \Rightarrow \forall u\in U :(ST)(u) = \vec{0}_U $ 
 $$ S(T(u))=\vec{0}_U\ $$

$\Rightarrow$ $\forall u\in U, T(u)\in Ker(S)$ $\Rightarrow$ $Im T \subseteq Ker(S)$

Right to left:

$Im T \subseteq Ker(S)$ $\Rightarrow$  $\forall u\in U, T(u)\in Ker(S)$

$\Rightarrow$ $ S(T(u))=\vec{0}_U\ $
$$ \forall u\in U, (ST)(u) = \vec{0}_U $$  $\Rightarrow$ $ U \subseteq Ker(ST) $ 
$$ \forall v \in Ker(ST) , v\in U $$ $\Rightarrow$ $ Ker(ST) \subseteq U $
$\Rightarrow$  $ U =  Ker(ST) $

$QED$

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, all is right.

Comment: Yep, just read through it too, looks perfect!

Comment: Many thanks to all critics and reviewers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer intends to remove the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

As already noted in the comments, your solution looks perfect.